# Spring security LDAP

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap

Spring Security does not found roles.

Configuration:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider
        user-search-filter="(cn={0})"
        user-search-base="OU=users,ou=gk,dc=corp,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
        group-search-filter="(&amp;(objectclass=group)(member={0}))"
        group-search-base="OU=groups,ou=gk,dc=corp,dc=mycompany,dc=com">
    </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

LOG:

```
Searching for roles for user 'terehin_gv', DN = 'cn=terehin_gv,ou=Users,ou=gk,dc=corp,dc=mycompany,dc=com', with filter (&(objectclass=group)(member={0})) in search base 'OU=Groups,ou=gk,dc=corp,dc=mycompany,dc=com'   |org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator
|[2016.10.12 09:37:16.277]|DEBUG|http-8443-2     |s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate| Using filter: (&(objectclass=group)(member=cn=terehin_gv,ou=Users,ou=gk,dc=corp,dc=mycompany,dc=com))   |org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate
|[2016.10.12 09:37:16.277]|DEBUG|http-8443-2     |efaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator| Roles from search: []   |org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator
```

In the ApacheDirectoryStudio of such a request is executed and displays the list of groups.